# Compile C# WPF and C++/Cli in a single exe

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

I have 2 projects in Visual Studio 2013; One is a C++/Cli project compiled as an exe, and the other is a C# WPF project compiled as a DLL.

The C++/Cli code calls the C# code and opens the WPF window.

The project works as intended when the C# project is compiled as a separate DLL, however I need the both projects to be compiled into a single exe.

Can this be done through visual studio?
If not, are there any alternatives?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/texblog/2007/04/05/linking-native-c-into-c-applications/

Comment: Try ILMerge utility.

Comment: ILMerge doesn't like mixed-mode assemblies, and WPF doesn't like ILMerge either :-) Instead, you could use [LibZ](https://github.com/MiloszKrajewski/LibZ) but you'd have to change your project structure - turn your C++/CLI project into a dll, and either use the C# project as an entry point or write a C# exe that will just call into the C++/CLI code. LibZ will embed the C++/CLI dependency into a resource, and it will unpack it to a temporary directory at runtime.

Comment: @Ðаn: The existing system we have requires a single exe, otherwise id be happy with an exe and seperate dll.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks, this looks promising!

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski: I've seen this method mentioned, but we cant easily change the project.